# bash operations on arrays using bc

Tags: bash, bc

from reading the man page of bc, it seems that bc can accept simple variables, but also arrays as input.

However, if I try to add two arrays, I only get a single element as an output

```
a=(1 2 3)
b=(10 11 12)
c=`echo "$a + $b" | bc`
```

Then c only contains 11.  If there a way to get bc to operate on all elements in the arrays to produce (11 13 15) as an output?  Or do I need to do a loop?

Comment: Your assignment will only *ever* make `c` a single string. Note that `"$a"` when `a` is an array refers implictly to `"${a[0]}"`.

Comment: bc isn't part of bash, so it can't read internal bash datastructures -- all communication between bash and bc is via generation and parsing of strings. Thus, `echo "$a + $b"` is generating a single string; bc can't see the original variables and has no way of knowing what their values were.

Comment: ...thus, bc has support for arrays in the same sense that Python or awk support arrays -- they *do*, but those arrays have nothing whatsoever to do with bash arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bc can't natively access bash arrays, but you can generate from your two arrays a stream of addition operations, and read their results back into a third array (thus only needing to invoke `bc` once, rather than running a separate copy of `bc` per loop entry):

```
a=(1 2 3)
b=(10 11 12)

readarray -t c < <(for idx in "${!a[@]}"; do
  echo "${a[$idx]} + ${b[$idx]}"
done | bc)
declare -p c              # print output as an array definition
printf '%s\n' "${c[@]}"   # print output one entry per line
```

See this running at https://ideone.com/YuPhQP, properly emitting as output:

```
declare -a c=([0]="11" [1]="13" [2]="15")
11
13
15
```